# Grouping Data every 2 minutes using group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that finds the total number of bits per minute, and groups them using the `group by` statement. I was wondering, how do I use the same `group by` statement to group  and sum the `totalBits` for every 2 minutes?

This is my set of queries for grouping for every one minute

```
SELECT SUM(totalBits ) AS totalBits,
EXTRACT( YEAR FROM timeStampID ) AS YEAR,
EXTRACT( MONTH FROM timeStampID ) AS MONTH ,
EXTRACT( DAY FROM timeStampID ) AS DAY ,
EXTRACT( HOUR FROM timeStampID ) AS HOUR ,
EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM timeStampID ) AS MINUTE ,
EXTRACT( SECOND FROM timeStampID ) AS SECOND FROM  `ipByteReceive1`
WHERE  `timeStampID` >  '2013-01-21 08:58:55'
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH , DAY , HOUR, MINUTE
```

This is what I get :

```
totalBits | YEAR | MONTH | DAY | HOUR | MINUTE
----------+------+-------+-----+------+--------
459       | 2013 | 1     | 21  | 8    | 58
2         | 2013 | 1     | 21  | 8    | 59
17        | 2013 | 1     | 21  | 9    | 00
```

This is what I would like to get :

```
totalBits | YEAR | MONTH | DAY | HOUR | MINUTE
----------+------+-------+-----+------+--------
461       | 2013 | 1     | 21  | 8    | 58
17        | 2013 | 1     | 21  | 9    | 00
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just change the way you extract minute to also do the grouping by 2, and drop second (since it won't mean anything anymore).

```
SELECT SUM(totalBits ) AS totalBits,
EXTRACT( YEAR FROM timeStampID ) AS YEAR, 
EXTRACT( MONTH FROM timeStampID ) AS MONTH ,
EXTRACT( DAY FROM timeStampID ) AS DAY , 
EXTRACT( HOUR FROM timeStampID ) AS HOUR , 
EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM timeStampID ) - MOD(EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM timeStampID ), 2) AS MINUTE , 
WHERE  `timeStampID` >  '2013-01-21 08:58:55'
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH , DAY , HOUR, MINUTE
```

Answer (score -1):

You should group by `MINUTE - MOD(MINUTE,2)` (and therefore select that instead of the column you currently select).

Comment: this extracts the sum of the bits only in the even minutes doesnt it? i want to add the bits in the odd rows as well..

Comment: yeah i did. it just sums up the total bits in the even minutes but ignores the bits when the minutes column is odd